# how to hide console window while running in C#

Tags: c#

How to hide the console window?

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

var handle = GetConsoleWindow();
ShowWindow(handle, 0);
```

I tried with this code, but the problem is that it is not completely hiding the window, instead it's minimizing the window.

Please suggest how to achieve completely hiding the window from foreground.

Comment: Is this about the console window of your own application? Why do you create a console app when you don't need the console window?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that you can't. Not in a guaranteed fashion. The longer answer requires a bit more discussion.

The issue is that you don't actually own the console window, and can't reliably get access to the window's handle. Even in the perfect case where your app is a console application targeting the 'Console' subsystem, the actual console window is owned by a different application: `conhost.exe`.

When you call [`GetConsoleWindow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolewindow) what you get back is a handle to a Windows object that handles Windows messages for your program, among other things, but isn't necessarily the actual console window. Often it's a pseudo-console instead, which handles things like the standard streams and so forth.

Console applications that you run will inherit your console, unless you specifically start them in their own separate one. Those programs can outlive your own, and can interact with the console all by themselves if you don't redirect their IO. It would be rude of them to hide the window while you're in the midst of prompting the user for input or some such, so they - and you - are not given the ability to do so.

***Note:*** since Windows 8 or so (according to [this article](https://www.mandiant.com/resources/blog/monitoring-windows-console-activity-part-one)) you don't ever interact with the console host directly. Instead you talk to it through IOCTL messages and shared memory.

What you can do however is either not create the console window at all (by targeting the 'Windows' subsystem) or disconnect your application from the console window using [`FreeConsole()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/freeconsole). If you're the last console application using that particular window then the relevant `conhost.exe` instance will exit, destroying the console with it. From that point on you're console-less until you decide you need a console window for something and call [`AllocConsole()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/allocconsole) to create a new console window (and new instance of `conhost.exe`) or [`AttachConsole()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/attachconsole) to connect to the console window of some other process.